# VSCode path generation failure in Run Build Task / tsc: build

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working through the Typescript intro at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

When I try to `Run Build Task` and choose `tsc: build`, VSCode attempts the following:

```
Executing task: tsc -p c:\work\JavascriptTypescript\test-apr-2018\tsconfig.json <

error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'c:workJavascriptTypescripttest-apr-2018tsconfig.json'.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

It is trying to use the full path to the tsconfig.json file, and then stripping the slashes from that path. Obviously this isn't going to find the correct file.

If I manually issue `tsc -p tsconfig.json` from the command line, `tsc` works correctly.

This seems like a VSCode configuration error, but I am new to VSCode and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known issue (as of 2018-04-20) when using VSCode on Windows with Git Bash as a terminal. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35593 .

Switching to CMD for a terminal is a workaround. So is invoking tsc manually as described above.

Answer (score 10):

Change the shell for tasks to `cmd.exe`

```
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
        "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    }
```

Now **you can keep `bash` as a shell** for the terminal and *build tasks* will be executed using `cmd.exe`

To change that value

1. open settings editor <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or File->Preferences->Settings
2. in a search, type `Automation`
3. Select `Edit in settings.json`
   [image]

**FYI**
[Can a task use a different shell than the one specified for the Integrated Terminal?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_can-a-task-use-a-different-shell-than-the-one-specified-for-the-integrated-terminal)

Comment: Confirming the issue still persists as of VSCode 1.85.2 using Git Bash as terminal. This is my preferred solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution to this problem is to create an npm script that runs tsc, and then run that script in the VSCode launch.json.

**package.json:**

`"scripts": {
    "debug": "tsc --sourcemap"
  },`

**.vscode/launch.json:**

`{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debugger",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: debug",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/*.js"
      ]
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you type the command:
"tsc -p c:\work\JavascriptTypescript\test-apr-2018\tsconfig.json"
in gitbash you get the same error.
If you change it to "tsc -p c:/work/JavascriptTypescript/test-apr-2018/tsconfig.json"
It will work